# I'm not able to edit my wordpress theme preloader

Tags: wordpress, themes, edit, preloader

here is the theme link "https://themeforest.net/item/ziptech-it-solutions-technology-wordpress-theme/45646783"

I have checked whole theme setting but not able to edit the preloader. I have tried using customize option but didn't find the option to change preloader text. i also tried theme options but still didn't find the option for that. so if anybody help me that would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just go to your dashboard,customize and  add this code on the "Add aditional CSS" option :

#preloader{display:none !important;}

It should stop the pre loader from displaying.